# How to access the RabbitMQ management console?

Tags: rabbitmq

I had installed RabbitMQ on my windows machine long back. Now I want to access its management console web page. I tried the default ports 5672, 25672, 15672, 5671, 15671, 25671. Not able to access the page. I checked under windows 'services' and found it to be up & running.

How can I access the RabbitMQ Management console? How can I find on which port my rabbitMQ is running?

Comment: You can use [portmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/portmon) to find out the port number.

Comment: The rabbitmq_management plugin has been enabled ? `rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management`

Comment: To see all the list of plugins `rabbitmq-plugins.bat list`.